# End the loop after all the images are compressed

Tags: python, k-means, image-compression

I am writing a program to compress all the images present in a folder. After all the images are compressed the loop does not end. How can I terminate after all the compression process ends.

```
def compress():
    algorithm = "full"
    for f in os.listdir('.'):
        if f.endswith('.png'):
            image = io.imread(f, 0)
            rows = image.shape[0]
            cols = image.shape[1]

            pixels = image.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
            kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=128, n_init=10, max_iter=200)
            kmeans.fit(pixels)

            clusters = np.asarray(kmeans.cluster_centers_, dtype=np.uint8)
            labels = np.asarray(kmeans.labels_, dtype=np.uint8)
            labels = labels.reshape(rows, cols)
            colored = clusters[labels]

            #  np.save('codebook'+f+'.npy', clusters)
            io.imsave('compressed_' + f, colored)

            img1 = mpimg.imread(f, 0)
            img2 = mpimg.imread('compressed_' + f, 0)
            fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 10))
            ax1.imshow(img1)
            ax1.set_title('Original image')
            ax2.imshow(img2)
            ax2.set_title('Compressed image')
            plt.show()

            fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

            img = cv2.imread(f, 0)
            ax[0].hist(img.ravel(), 256, [0, 256]);
            ax[0].set_title("Original image")
            img1 = cv2.imread('compressed_' + f, 0)
            ax[1].hist(img1.ravel(), 256, [0, 256]);
            ax[1].set_title("Compressed image")
            plt.show()

            print('size of original image: ', int(os.stat(f).st_size / 1024), 'kB')
            print('size of compressed image:', int(os.stat('compressed_' + f).st_size / 1024), 'kB')
```

Comment: Two things: (1) the `for` loop should end when it has parsed all of the files, so you might need to do some debugging to see if the loop is hanging / looping infinitely within the top-level `for` for some reason - the only reason it would continue forever is if it hasn't finished looking at all the files in `.`, (2) you're probably better to filter out the `.png` files and only loop through those (eg. `for f in [x for x in test_data if x.endswith(".png")]:`)

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner +1 for (1), but what benefit does (2) have?

Comment: @glglgl for (2), you can then ditch the "if" statement at the top since you'll only be looking at .png files - it's just a style consideration... IIUC Python has a bunch of optimizations built-in if you follow the various fun python ways of doing things (including because it defaults to C in a lot of common us cases, which is faster than Python), so there might be a very minor speed increase as well.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner Ok, so just a stylistic question rather than a real improvement of program flow. BTW, I'd probably do a generator expression than a list comprehension here, but in the end, it doesn't really matter.